# Anylogic - Automate multiple runs of a simulation model in Anylogic

Tags: java, bash, anylogic

I have a simulation model written in Anylogic. The output of the simulation is automatically exported to an excel file. I need to **run the simulation about 20 times** for each of the 10 scenarios and it each run takes about 30 minutes for each run.

How can I automate this process? Also, I want to be able to pass a few arguments to the model for each run.

Comment: What would you like to automate? The output writing process? Or having 20 runs?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I would like to automate 20 runs and be able to pass a few arguments to the model for each run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `Parameters Variation` experiment.

You can access any run number on Main startup with the code `int a=getEngine().getRunCount();`. You can prepare the inputs beforehand in an Excel and pass the parameters based on the count number.
[image]

You can write the outputs separately for each run. Use the following code as an inspiration where I write `myVariable` at the end of each run to csv files called output0.csv, ouput1.csv, etc. (This happens in Main -> On Destroy.

```
int a=getEngine().getRunCount();

String filename="output"+a+".csv";

try
{
 FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(filename);
 PrintStream p = new PrintStream(fos);
 
 for (int i=0; i<100;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<10;j++){
        p.println(myVariable.output[i][j]);}} // outputs tab delimited values
}
catch (Exception e)
{
 traceln("Could not write to file.");
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Yashar. Parameter variation solves the problem.